# Django runserver command doesn't stop

Tags: python, django, command-prompt, windows-10

I was using django on my windows 8.1 rpoperly , and its command line commands run properly. But after i upgrade it to windows 10, i can't close cammand prompt from regular X icon (I must write `exit` to exit from command prompt or kill it by task manager), and when i run  `$ python manage.py runserver`  it's not stoped by  `ctrl-c`  or any other hotkeys.
 I kill process by using **task manager**, and again go to directory of project.
How can i fix these problem?

Comment: Try to uninstall Python and Django and install it again.

Comment: does the problem exist after a restart?

Comment: yes if i run server  i cant stop it

Comment: I think it is a OS problem, not from Django.